# Find the origin of FOV given samples in 2D

Tags: matlab, image-processing, 2d, distribution, best-fit

I have a fun problem that I'm trying to solve. I've been given a data set from a sensor in Cartesian coordinates. This data is very dense so there is no shortage of points.

Now assuming that the origin of this data is at (0,0) I want to find the potential offset of the sensor in that frame.

My attempt was to create the convex hull of this data set, and then check for groups of intersecting lines which's intersection lies within a certain distance from the origin point. This give a good approximation using this ideal data, [Click Me](http://i60.tinypic.com/8y6epu.jpg).

In Link 1 you see a few green lines, these are the "Mainline" I've taken from the convex hull that are good candidates to use. There are a lot of them since the image is done from a loop.

Now, to my problem. The data I get is noisy so there are many outlying points, that is, points that are really outside the FOV but still get measured. These bad points are few, but enough so that the convex hull approach does not work (I've tried alpha shapes as well, it does work better but still not good enough).

I was wondering if you have any ideas to what direction I could go to solve this dilemma? Preferably I'd like to extract this origin point as binomial distribution.

Here is an example image of raw data (although I've changed it and removed data for IP reasons). [Click Me](http://i60.tinypic.com/8y6epu.jpg).

An idea I had was maybe work with the data in polar coordinates, and then use dohougs transform to extract "clear" straight lines in polar coordinates, which could give me a set of arc lengths at a certain distance R and then somehow go from there?

P.S.
Sorry for few links, only allowed to put two here and now images :/

Comment: Have you tried combining your two suggestions? Use the convex/alpha shape hull to define trials locations. Then for each trial location, convert to polar and detect lines. The trial location that detects the most/strongest lines is a best candidate. You can then refine the answer by searching near that best candidate using the same polar transform/Hough detection method.

Comment: Interesting idea. I could definitely do that, but then I'd have to trust that at least one of the candidates from the convex/alpha hull are the right one.

But when looking at the raw data, its clear that in many cases this wont be true. I think my best bet is somehow figuring out a best fit optimization problem using this large set of data, but haven't figured anything out yet.

Comment: Actually, you don't have to trust that one of the candidates is the right one. You just have to trust that it will get you in the right ballpark. The second part of my suggestion was to use the best candidate as the starting point to then do a refinement search. Set up a search grid around the best candidate and then repeat your polar/Hough detection.